# get first characters of expansion parameter of find command

Tags: bash, find, rename

I have a huge collection of images and I would like to put them in folders matching their first 3 charachers+.jpg extension.

So i would like to grab `4_1_0002.png` file (all the files starting with 4_1) and put it in the `4_1_.jpg` folder. Similarly I would like to grab `4_2_0002.png` file (all the files starting with 4_2) and put it in the `4_2_.jpg` folder.

All those files that I would like to sort are now in one huge folder.
I expected to use a find command, but I don't know how to extract the first three characters from {} expansion parameter.

```
find . -type f -ok echo mv {} "path/first3char.jpg" \;
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
src="/pathto/large_folder"
dest="/tmp/3chars"

mkdir -p "$dest" || exit 1

cd "$src" && \
find . -type f -name '???*' -exec sh -c '
   for f
   do
      b=${f##*/}
      d=${b%"${b#???}"}_.jpg
      [ -d "$dest/$d" ] || mkdir -p "$dest/$d"
      mv "$f" "$dest/$d/."
   done
' x {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

There are tools that make renaming files a lot easier. For example, using any of the Perl `rename` implementations, often available under the name `prename`:

```
prename '$dir = substr($_,0,3); mkdir $dir; $_ = "$dir/$_"' *.jpg
```

If the directories already exist, you can simplify this to

```
prename 's!(...)!$1/$1!' *.jpg
```

If your distribution doesn't carry `prename`, install one, for example [Unicode::Tussle](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode::Tussle) or [File::Rename](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Rename).

`find` is probably not useful here since the files are all in the same directory. However, you may run into an error because the command line is too long. `find` is one way to solve this; you can use

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name '*.jpg' -exec prename 's!(...)!$1/$1!' {} +
```

Alternatively, run [zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) instead of bash, and take advantage of its [`zmv` function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv).

```
autoload zmv        # you can put this in ~/.zshrc
mkdir_mv () {
  mkdir -p -- $2:h
  mv -- $1 $2
}
zmv -p mkdir_mv '(???)*.jpg' '$1/$f'
```

If the directories already exist, you can use just

```
zmv '(???)*.jpg' '$1/$f'
```